# Python classes: method has same name as property

Tags: python, class

I'm constructing a class, *Heating*. Every instance of this class has the property 'temperature'. It's mandatory that *Heating* also supports the method *temperature()* that prints the property 'temperature' as an integer.

When I call the method temperature(), I get the error

> 'int' object is not callable because self.temperature is already defined as an integer.

How do I solve this?

Code:

```
class Heating:
    """
    >>> machine1 = Heating('radiator kitchen', temperature=20)
    >>> machine2 = Heating('radiator living', minimum=15, temperature=18)
    >>> machine3 = Heating('radiator bathroom', temperature=22, minimum=18, maximum=28)
    >>> print(machine1)
    radiator kitchen: current temperature: 20.0; allowed min: 0.0; allowed max: 100.0
    >>> machine2
    Heating('radiator living', 18.0, 15.0, 100.0)
    >>> machine2.changeTemperature(8)
    >>> machine2.temperature()
    26.0
    >>> machine3.changeTemperature(-5)
    >>> machine3
    Heating('radiator bathroom', 18.0, 18.0, 28.0)
    """
    def __init__(self, name, temperature = 10, minimum = 0, maximum = 100):
        self.name = name
        self.temperature = temperature
        self.minimum = minimum
        self.maximum = maximum

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0}: current temperature: {1:.1f}; allowed min: {2:.1f}; allowed max: {3:.1f}'.format(self.name, self.temperature, self.minimum, self.maximum)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Heating(\'{0}\', {1:.1f}, {2:.1f}, {3:.1f})'.format(self.name, self.temperature, self.minimum, self.maximum)

    def changeTemperature(self, increment):
        self.temperature += increment

        if self.temperature < self.minimum:
            self.temperature = self.minimum

        if self.temperature > self.maximum:
            self.temperature = self.maximum

    def temperature(self):
        return self.temperature


# Test of the program
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: You can't have both a method and an attribute with the same name. Methods are attributes too, albeit ones that you can call.

Comment: the method to return `Heating.temperature` should be called something else like `Heating.get_temperature()`

Comment: Also, you don't have a *property* here, you have just an attribute. A property is a special kind of object that you *access* as an attribute (without a call) but that then automatically calls a method.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can't have both a method and an attribute with the same name. Methods are attributes too, albeit ones that you can call.

Just rename the attribute to something else. You could use `_temperature`:

```
def __init__(self, name, temperature = 10, minimum = 0, maximum = 100):
    self.name = name
    self._temperature = temperature
    self.minimum = minimum
    self.maximum = maximum

def __str__(self):
    return '{0}: current temperature: {1:.1f}; allowed min: {2:.1f}; allowed max: {3:.1f}'.format(self.name, self._temperature, self.minimum, self.maximum)

def __repr__(self):
    return 'Heating(\'{0}\', {1:.1f}, {2:.1f}, {3:.1f})'.format(self.name, self._temperature, self.minimum, self.maximum)

def changeTemperature(self, increment):
    self._temperature += increment

    if self.temperature < self.minimum:
        self._temperature = self.minimum

    if self.temperature > self.maximum:
        self._temperature = self.maximum

def temperature(self):
    return self._temperature
```

Now your class has both `_temperature` (the integer) and `temperature()` (the method); the latter returns the former.

Comment: I also had the same issue and followed the same convention and it worked.
But, I would like to know more about, How a method is also an attribute?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelKhalek: you can access the name of a method on a class *without calling it*. Functions are also descriptors, which is how binding works, see https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html for more details.