# Using a leading underscore to avoid conflicts with attributes and methods

Tags: python, pep8

My initial question was; how do I format attribute and method names that are identical? This question was answered by Martijn [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39210250/python-classes-method-has-same-name-as-property). Martijn suggested adding a leading underscore to the attribute name, but after reading [the docs](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables), I was under the impression it would imply the attribute is private. Am I conflating instance attributes with class attributes? Does having a leading underscore for a class attribute not necessarily mean the attribute is private?

```
import random


class RandomName:
    def __init__(self, _name=None):
        self._name = _name

    def name(self):
        common_male_names = ['James', 'John', 'Robert', 'Michael', 'William', 'David', 'Richard', 'Joseph', 'Thomas',
                             'Charles']
        chosen_name = random.choice(common_male_names)
        self._name = chosen_name
```

Is the _name attribute private? Thanks! :)

Comment: The leading _ is just for naming convention. It does not affect the variable in any way. It just tells the next developer that the *_variable* is private

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as "private" in python.  Some people use a leading underscore as a convention indicating that a member should be treated as though it were private, but this is purely a social convention, not part of the language.

That said, in your particular example, given that you're providing an accessor method for `_temperature`, why *shouldn't* people consider it private?  They should just access it by calling `temperature` rather than by looking at it directly.

Comment: I understand Python does not have access modifiers. So in my RandomName class, the _name attribute isn't actually Private, but it can be if you want? LOL

Comment: Yes: anyone with an instance of RandomName can change r._name to whatever they want, or even delete it from the object entirely.

Comment: I guess this is where people's preferences come in, and why it can get contentious. Thanks Daniel.