# unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'method' and 'int'

Tags: python

I don't know why but getting the `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'method' and 'int'`

```
class Person:
  count_instance = 0 
  def __init__(self,first,last,age):
    Person.count_instance +=1
    self.first = first
    self.last = last
    self.age = age

  @classmethod
  def count_instance(cls):
    return f"You have created {cls.count_instance} instances of {cls.__name__} class"

  def full_name(self):
    return f"{self.first} {self.last}"

  def is_above_18(self):
    return self.age>18

p1 = Person("yup","gup",21)
p2 = Person('akshhu','yes',27)
print(Person.count_instance)
```

Comment: Because you are trying to gave a class attribute and a class method (also an attribute) with the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `count_instance` as method name and variable name.
So changing the `count_instance` variable to other name like `count_instance_var` will solve the issue

```
class Person:
  count_instance_var = 0 
  def __init__(self,first,last,age):
    Person.count_instance_var +=1
    self.first = first
    self.last = last
    self.age = age

  @classmethod
  def count_instance(cls):
    return f"You have created {cls.count_instance_var} instances of {cls.__name__} class"

  def full_name(self):
    return f"{self.first} {self.last}"

  def is_above_18(self):
    return self.age>18

p1 = Person("yup","gup",21)
p2 = Person('akshhu','yes',27)
print(Person.count_instance_var)
```

If you are trying to call the class method, please use `Person.count_instance()`

```
class Person:
  count_instance_var = 0 
  def __init__(self,first,last,age):
    Person.count_instance_var +=1
    self.first = first
    self.last = last
    self.age = age

  @classmethod
  def count_instance(cls):
    return f"You have created {cls.count_instance_var} instances of {cls.__name__} class"

  def full_name(self):
    return f"{self.first} {self.last}"

  def is_above_18(self):
    return self.age>18

p1 = Person("yup","gup",21)
p2 = Person('akshhu','yes',27)
print(Person.count_instance())
```

Comment: Ok, now I understand Thank you

Answer (score 0):

looks like you're calling the method count_instance not the variable. based on this answer you'll need to change either the method name or the var name as they cant be the same.
[Python classes: method has same name as property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39210250/python-classes-method-has-same-name-as-property)